# Combine multiple MySql queries into a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have table name users.

```
id   name date       cdate           c  a   b
1     rz  42121221  42121221         0  1   0
2     an  12122111  42121221         0  0   1
3     cb  22121221  42121221         1  1   1   
4     ss  3321221   42121221         1  0   0
```

i have two select the values between two dates,and then i have to find the count using this statement.

```
 SELECT COALESCE(SUM(IF(c=1 AND a=0 AND b=1  ,  1, 0)),0) AS ACTIVE WHERE DATE BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2',COALESCE(SUM(IF(c=0 AND a=0 AND b=1  ,  1, 0)),0) AS INC WHERE cdate BETWEEN 'DATE 1' AND 'DATE 2' FROM users
```

this query is not working

Comment: What's your expected outcome? Where's the second query?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a single statement? What benefit will this give you?

Comment: first i want to get the values between two dates then i have to use this query SELECT COALESCE(SUM(IF(c=1 AND a=0 AND b=1  ,  1, 0)),0) AS ACTIVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like

```
select COALESCE(SUM(IF(c=1 AND a=0 AND b=1  ,  1, 0)),0) AS ACTIVE from users where date between 'date1' and date '2'
```